# sqlite autoincrement not work correctly

Tags: android, sqlite, auto-increment

I've created this table but the auto increment connected together doesn't work properly and if i write auto increment separated it doesn't give any error but the id still (firstTableColumns[8]) 0 and doesn't incremented

```
db.execSQL("create table feedFirstTable ('"+firstTableColumns[0]+"' text  primary key ,'"+firstTableColumns[1]+"' text,'"+firstTableColumns[2]+"' text,'"+firstTableColumns[3]+"' text,'"+firstTableColumns[4]+"' text ,'"+firstTableColumns[5]+"'  text  ,'"+firstTableColumns[6]+"'  text ,'"+firstTableColumns[7]+"'  text ,'"+firstTableColumns[8]+"'  long unique autoincrement  );");
```

Comment: and I've tried without unique and it also gives error

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, an autoincrementing columns must be declared as [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Answer (score 0):

Set your auto increment as integer.
Why do you use firstTableColumns[8] as an auto increment id instead of using the primary key of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE feedFirstTable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,...
```

Comment: i want auto increment to count data,where the primary key differs,since it represents id of downloaded image